# isotope filter - prevent "selected" category from loading all images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-isotope

I've tried the suggested fixes on Stack Overflow but can't seem to fix my issue.  I'm trying to get a "selected" category to keep from loading all the images on page load.  I've tried to remove the "Show All" line but that does not help.  I believe this to be a js problem.

Here's my html and js:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="isotope-options">
<ul id="isotope-filters" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".isotope-filter2"   class="selected">Recital Photos</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".isotope-filter1">Home Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".isotope-filter3">Recital   Videos</a></li>    
</ul>            
</div>
```

**JS:**

I couldn't fit all the js here, so here's a link: 
[isotope filter js](http://www.boulderdrumstudio.com/js/jquery.isotope.min.js)

Here's the code you requested:

```
<li class="span3 isotope-element isotope-filter2">
    <div class="thumb-isotope">
        <div class="thumbnail clearfix">
            <a href="gallery_images/recital_pics/1pm hippie group.jpg">
                <div class="banner_inner">
                <div class="banner_inner2">
                <figure>
                    <img src="gallery_images/recital_pics/1pm hippie group - sm.jpg" alt=""><em></em>
                </figure>
                <div class="caption">                           
                    Group 1
                </div>
                </div>  
                </div>
                <img src="images/banner_shadow.png" alt="" class="banner_shadow">   
            </a>                
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Posting a link to isotope.js isn't going to help (BTW, that version is old, current is v3). We need to see the code your using to call isotope and set filters.

Comment: Good to know...js is now updated to v3.

Comment: OP revised to include requested code.

Comment: You don't need to link to the isotope plugin itself. That is not where the js problem is and not something anyone will advise changing or altering. The code we need to see is the javascript for your page that initiates the isotope plugin, not the plugin itself. BTW, You posted your html code, not javascript code.

Comment: As I explained above, I provided a link to the js as SO prevented its posting due to an excess of characters in the script.  That's the best I can do.  See above link...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using this

```
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.selected' });
```